# Imagen venctorizada SVG no se muestra en IE, Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

estoy intentando insertar una imagen vectorizada en formato SVG, pero solo la logro ver en mozilla firefox, para IE y chrome no aparece. He buscado un poco de documentación sobre svg en navegadors, en muchos veo ejemplos dónde se  dibujan formas colocando coordenadas, colores y el navegador renderiza  en imagen svg, pero en mi casa tengo en archivo ese imagen svg.

Código :

```
   <div class= "spacioLogos">
         <p:graphicImage value="./images/logo_mexico.svg" width="120" height="55" styleClass="logoizquierda"/>

         <p:graphicImage value="./images/logo_mexico.svg" width="120" height="55" styleClass="img"/>                    

    </div>
```

Lo mismo se ve si coloco el html img:

```
<img src="./images/logo_mexico.svg" width="120" height="55" class="responsive" />
```

Muestra  de como se renderiza en navegadores:
mozila firefox:
[image: Mozilla firefox]

google chrome:
[image: Google chrome]

internet explorer edge:
[image: Internet explorer edge]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido del SVG?

Comment: Hola @Voiser, veo que has encontrado la solución; por favor, añade la solución como una respuesta (abajo dice responde tu propia pregunta o similar), así otros usuarios en el futuro pueden hallarla fácilmente y beneficiarse de ella. Salu2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quedo solucionado, modifiqué el web.xml de mi aplicación agregando el type-mime de imagenes svg, con esto ya se muestran en Mozilla firefox, IE, y Chrome.

```
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svgz</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```