# problemas con iconos svg en google chrome

Tags: html, css, html5, web, svg

Lo que ocurre es que estoy añadiendo unos iconos .svg pero estoy presentando problemas ya que en Firefox se muestran sin inconvenientes, pero en Chrome simplemente no se muestran.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 448 512"><use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#instagram-ico"></use></svg>
```

Asi los estoy intentando mostrar sin embargo hay uno de una flecha que si se muestra a diferencia de los de redes sociales :

```
<svg class="btn-widht-ico-right" viewBox="0 0 13 9"><use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#arrow-right"></use></svg>
```

Que podria ser? como puedo hacer que Chrome los reconozca?

Comment: Por favor creá un [mcve].

Comment: No tengo claro como puede esto funcionar en Firefox. Me gustaría ver un ejemplo que funciona. Mientras tanto podrías utilizar una imagen. Por ejemplo así: `<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat" />`

Comment: Quizás te pueda servir esta otra respuesta. [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24837/imagen-venctorizada-svg-no-se-muestra-en-ie-chrome)